# File input widget in Shiny for AWS

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working with R studio in an AWS enviroinment, and my files are stored in S3 bucket.

I am developing a User interface in Shiny and would like to upload the files from S3 instead from the system.

My below code works for uploading file from system.

```
ui<- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("File Input"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file","Upload the file"), # fileinput() function is used to get the file upload contorl option
      helpText("Default max. file size is 5MB"),
      tags$hr(),
      h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
      checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
      checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
      br(),
      radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tb")
    )

  )
))

server <-shinyServer(function(input,output){
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)

  })
  output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  })

  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())

  })


  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })


  output$tb <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(data()))
      h5("Powered by", tags$img(src='RStudio-Ball.png', heigth=200, width=200))
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
  })
})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

could anyone suggest me how I could do it for uploading from bucket.

Also, with the above code, I am getting an error "line1 , didnot have 7 elements".

any inputs would be helpful,